# Return two rows from database using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

This query works as I want but only returns one value.

```
public function get_doctor_name($doctor_id)  {
  $result = $this->db->query("SELECT first_name, last_name from doctors where id= $municipio_id")->row_array();
  return $result['first_name'];
}
```

How to return the `last_name` as I did for `first_name` in the same query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is actually correct.

However, you can use `return $result->result_array();` to get an array of all fields, first_name, last_name etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can return array:

```
return $result;
```

You can return a string, for example:

```
return $result['first_name'] . ' ' . $result['last_name'];
```

You can return array with specific keys that you define:

```
return [
    'f_name' => $result['first_name'], 
    'l_name' => $result['last_name']
];
```

Comment: return $result['first_name'] . ' ' . $result['last_name']; this i exactly what i wanted. After 4 minutes i will accept your answer. Thanks